# Slow join on multiple conditions

Tags: t-sql, join, sql-server-2012

That join [docSVsys] as [docSVsysReturn] is killing the query
The three condition join is killing it - it turn into a loop join
It take over 2 minutes
If I take out the or( [docSVsysReturn].[sParID] = [coreCTE].[sParID] and [docSVsysReturn].[sParID] = [docSVsysReturn].[sID] ) it runs in 1 second s 
I tried merge and hash join but they are not allowed
A columns involved are indexed
[sID] is the PK and  [sParID] is required and a FK to [sID]
Any thoughts on how to fix performance?

```
; WITH coreCTE AS (
  select [docSVsysAuth].[sID], [docSVsysAuth].[sParID]
    from [docSVsys] as [docSVsysAuth] with (nolock)
    join [docSVtext] as [Table] with (nolock)
      on [Table].[sID] = [docSVsysAuth].[sID]
     and [docSVsysAuth].[visibility] in (0)
     and [Table].[fieldID] = '108'
   where [table].[value]  = 'Andy Wipper<andy.wipper@company.com>' 
)  
,      [cteFinal] AS (
select distinct [docSVsysReturn].[sID], [docSVsysReturn].[sParID]
  from [coreCTE] 
  join [docSVsys] as [docSVsysReturn] with (nolock) 
    on ( [docSVsysReturn].[sID] = [coreCTE].[sID]
          or
         ( [docSVsysReturn].[sParID] = [coreCTE].[sParID] and [docSVsysReturn].[sParID] = [docSVsysReturn].[sID] )
       )
   and [docSVsysReturn].[visibility] in (0)
)
select [cteFinal].[sID], [cteFinal].[sParID] 
  from [cteFinal]
 order by [cteFinal].[sID], cteFinal.[sParID]
```

this helped a bit

```
on ( [docSVsysReturn].[sID] = [coreCTE].[sID]
      or
     ( [docSVsysReturn].[sID] <> [coreCTE].[sID] and [docSVsysReturn].[sParID] = [coreCTE].[sParID] and [docSVsysReturn].[sParID] = [docSVsysReturn].[sID] )
   )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going at from a different angle fixed it
Basically put the OR later in the game

```
; WITH coreCTE AS (
  select distinct [docSVsysAuth].[sID], [docSVsysAuth].[sParID]
  from [docSVsys] as [docSVsysAuth] with (nolock)
  join [docSVtext] as [Table] with (nolock)
  on [Table].[sID] = [docSVsysAuth].[sID]
  and [docSVsysAuth].[visibility] in (0)
  and [Table].[fieldID] = '108'
  where ((    [table].[value]  = 'Andy Wipper<andy.wipper@company.com>' )
  )
)
,      [cteFinal] AS (
select distinct [docSVsysReturn].[sID], [docSVsysReturn].[sParID]
  from [coreCTE] 
  join [docSVsys] as [docSVsysReturn] with (nolock) 
    on ( [docSVsysReturn].[sParID] = [coreCTE].[sParID]
         and
         (     [docSVsysReturn].[sID] = [coreCTE].[sID]  -- the document
           or  (      [docSVsysReturn].[sParID] = [docSVsysReturn].[sID] -- it is a parent
                  and [coreCTE].[sParID] <> [coreCTE].[sID] -- already have the parent
                  and [docSVsysReturn].[visibility] in (0)
               ) -- or the parent
         )
       )
)
select [cteFinal].[sID], [cteFinal].[sParID] -- ,bulkUpField 
  from [cteFinal]
 order by [cteFinal].[sID], cteFinal.[sParID]
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you try to write the query with a `UNION` instead. Try it out.

```
select [docSVsysReturn].[sID], [docSVsysReturn].[sParID]
  from [coreCTE] 
  join [docSVsys] as [docSVsysReturn] with (nolock) 
    on [docSVsysReturn].[sID] = [coreCTE].[sID]
   and [docSVsysReturn].[visibility] in (0)

UNION

select [docSVsysReturn].[sID], [docSVsysReturn].[sParID]
  from [coreCTE] 
  join [docSVsys] as [docSVsysReturn] with (nolock) 
    on [docSVsysReturn].[sParID] = [coreCTE].[sParID] 
   and [docSVsysReturn].[sParID] = [docSVsysReturn].[sID]
   and [docSVsysReturn].[visibility] in (0)
```

Comment: This work but I am building the query up in a program and have many other conditions and a UNION would just be a LOT of work

Comment: `or`'s in joins are very hard to optimize. Possibly the plan can be optimized by adding various indexes to the columns involved. Otherwise you might me stuck with going the `union` way.

Comment: Every column is indexed.  Nothing but index seeks in the query plan.  See my fix.